# Issue with MOKO Resource Library: Images Directory Not Generated for Compose Multiplatform

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I am currently utilizing the MOKO resource library to share resources across a Compose multiplatform project. While the build process seems to work seamlessly for string resources, I am encountering an issue with the generation of the images directory.

Directory Structure:

```
-resources 
--MR 
---ar
---base
---images
----splash.png
```

Observations:

The strings resource directory is generated correctly, and I can access the string resource IDs without any issues.
The images directory, however, does not seem to be generated successfully during the build process.
I attempted to resolve the issue by downgrading the MOKO dependency, but this did not yield any positive results.
Steps Taken:

I have meticulously followed the official MOKO documentation to ensure correct implementation.
I searched extensively online for similar issues but couldn't find any relevant solutions or discussions.
I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to address this problem. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue, and if so, please help.

Comment: this might help someone, the issue is that. found out i'm using wrong naming conventions for the Images resources. If we add the following files to commonMain/resources/MR/images:    <home_black_18@1x.png>/ <home_black_18@2x.png> there should be a prefix for scale image@(n)x.jpeg